# PageView.builder constantly re-caches static images

Tags: android, image, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a music playing screen where swiping on the album art plays the next track. I am using PageView.builder to populate the list of tracks.

I enabled the checkerboardRasterCacheImages flag and screencap'd a video. Here's the link: https://streamable.com/1oi6h

The issue is that album image is constantly being re-cached which causes dropped frames which is resulting in sub-60 fps scenes.

I tried wrapping my widget with a RepaintBoundary widget but it still re-caches the images. 
Also tried removing the background blur.

```
                      AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: 1.0 / 1.0,
                        child: Container(
                          width: media.size.width,
                          child: PageView.builder(
                              controller: _pageController,
                              onPageChanged: (int idx) {
                                if (idx < _pageController.page)
                                  prev();
                                else
                                  next();
                              },
                              itemCount: widget.playlist.length(),
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return Padding(
                                  padding: media.padding.add(
                                      EdgeInsets.all(40)),
                                  child: DecoratedBox(
                                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                        image: DecorationImage(
                                          image: widget.playlist
                                              .get(index)
                                              .albumArt,
                                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                        ),
                                        boxShadow: [
                                          new BoxShadow(
                                              color: Colors.black
                                                  .withOpacity(
                                                  0.5),
                                              offset: new Offset(2.0, 2.0),
                                              blurRadius: 5.0,
                                              spreadRadius: 5.0)
                                        ]
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              }),
                        ),
                      ),
```

I'm expecting since it is a static image, it shouldn't re-cache every frame. Also, this is my first app and first time posting here so if more info/code is needed please don't hesitate to ask for whatever is needed.
Thanks.